# OpenNI + OpenCV don't work with CV_CAP_OPENNI C++

Tags: opencv, kinect, openni

I'm trying to use OpenCV with Kinect on Windows 7 x64, so I installed OpenNI, NITE and PrimeSense (by avin2).

I used CMake to compile the OpenCV 2.3.1, everything is correct with CMake Flags I checked, but I tried to use a simple code and it never found the Kinect.

All the samples of OpenNI and PrimeSense work fine.
I already installed x86 and x64 drivers and it still doesn't work!

I'm using VideoCapture, and isOpened, always returns 0.

Anyone know the solution?

Answer (score 1):

I did that under linux ubuntu 12.04 last week end and that work fine.

Try to re-install componant by componant, and recompile your openCV.

I did that last week end.

But I agree there is things wich are not clear about how deal with that.
I replaced the kinect by an assus xtion and right now that don't work... but this an other topic.

About PrimeSense hardware, as I khnow kinect is made by PrimeSense... moreover PrimeSense is a member of the OpenNI project which is use in background of the libraries P.C.L. , openCV, and on the ros's openni_camera stack...

Answer (score 1):

I have installed the opencv kinect on windows 7-64its (Professional) and works fine.

1.Drivers to kinect: [here](http://code.google.com/p/simple-openni/downloads/detail?name=OpenNI_NITE_Installer-win32-0.27.zip&can=2&q=)

**Note**

- When you to install the dirvers make sure that the "Windows update" will not install aditional
  drivers.

  Tip: Disconnect the internet when you install it. ;)
- Check in the "Device Manager" and search for PrimeSense.

  Something like this:

  - PrimeSense
    |- Kinect Audio
    |- Kinect Camera
    |- Kinect Motor

Check if it's working. Run a OpenNI sample.

2.OpenCV

Download it:

...://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/files/opencv-win/2.3.1/OpenCV-2.3.1-win-superpack.exe/download

Configure the opencv on cmake. Remeber check to on the "OpenNI" option.
Maybe you'll get an erro like "warning: PrimeSense..." this happen because the OpenCVFindOpenNI.cmake is outdated.

You have to do some changes.
Go to here and download the changes:

Click [here](https://code.ros.org/trac/opencv/attachment/ticket/1339/OpenCVFindOpenNI.patch) and download it (at bottom of page: "Download in other formats: Original Format").

You have to do the changes in the original file "OpenCVFindOpenNI.cmake". 
It's in the root folder "OpenCV-2.3.1\"

The line that has "-" you delete and the line tha has "+" you replace/add.

Configure and compile the openCV.
After this it'll works fine, at least it should... :)

Sure.. You have to compile... ;)
I my case - Visual Studio C++ 9(2008) - (I compiled in the Release mode only)

You have to set the "bin" in the patch of system after compile..

Run a sample:

> "OpenCV-2.3.1\samples\cpp\kinect_maps.cpp" and enjoy.

Comment: please update your link after line "Go to here and download the changes:".. its not woriking

Answer (score 0):

kinect for windows perhaps is not supported by Primesenser hardware drivers or even by avin2

Comment: This shouldn't be an answer. If you don't actually know, then you shouldn't answer the question.